# How to create menu like this in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, menu

How do I make a small menu like the one below come up when a button is pressed.

[image]

The only difference is instead of the options in the image, how do I show buttons. I could't find an example with buttons.

Comment: You have to customize UIActivityViewController and add custom activities

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for sharing, use `UIActivityViewController`

http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Otherwise you can use a custom UIView and add anything in it and give it a frame and animate it from the bottom of the screen when your button is pressed